# CSS - Allow an div to stick out of its parent

Tags: html, css

I've been searching a lot for a way to allow a div to stick out of its parent.

The parent has float:right and I'm trying to make clicking it toggle show/hide a child element, but the child element shows/hides after the div. I'd like to make it "stick out" of the parent div.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried so far.

Comment: How constrained are you on structure? If you want to do it this way, you can simply not have the second element be a child; place it on the page independantly if the parent, and make sure the visible property doesn't inherit..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your explanation is not very clear, but here is a demo of a right-aligned parent div with a child div that sticks out. I hope that is what you're looking for :)

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Parent
  <div id="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

overflow: visible; on parent should do the trick - be careful if you have and dimensions set mind!!!

Comment: Let's say other elements overflow but you want those elements to scroll. Then your approach fails. This needs arises with custom drop down elements.