# Stick an element out of its container

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'd like to have a header with one sticky element and one non-sticky element. Hence, the structure would be something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  position: static;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: visible;
}

.sticky-yes {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.sticky-no {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="sticky-yes">Sticky</div>
  <div class="sticky-no">Not sticky</div>
</header>
<div>... Rest of the webpage ...</div>
```

The header sits as a direct child of the body.

As far as I know, sticky elements want to stick to the nearest ancestor with a "scrolling mechanism". And I can "ignore" the parent element by giving it `position: static;`

I also added `overflow: visible;` to the parent after reading this related question: [CSS - Allow an div to stick out of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637745/css-allow-an-div-to-stick-out-of-its-parent)

But this snippet won't work.

I am constrained to use it with that markup, I cannot move the sticky element outside of the header.

What approach can I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of creative CSS.  Adds a bit of maintenance but does stick the element.  Note here I sized both elements and used that as the base height of the header.  I also used box-sizing to avoid issues with this is zoomed in a browser.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 2000px;
  --sticky-height: 3rem;
  --non-sticky-height: 2rem;
  --header-height: calc(var(--sticky-height) + var(--non-sticky-height));
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  height: var( --header-height);
}

.sticky-yes {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: var(--sticky-height);
}

.sticky-no {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  top: var(--sticky-height);
  height: var(--non-sticky-height);
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="sticky-yes">Sticky</div>
  <div class="sticky-no">No</div>
</header>
```

Comment: That's REALLY some creative CSS there. It's cool, thanks.